# Finding a key in an object by using values from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an array which is dynamically created by selecting items from a list:

```
[2, 4]
```

I also have an array of objects:

```
[{id: 1, name: "Param1"}, {id: 2, name: "Param2"}, {id: 3, name: "Param3"}, {id: 4, name: "Param4"}]
```

What I need to do is use the values in the first array to match against the ids in the objects in the second array and return those objects.

Help with this would be much appreciated

Thanks for your time

Comment: Just use a for loop. This is very stright forward. Have you attempted this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this ES6 code, which turns the first array to a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to allow fast lookup, and then applies the Array [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method, specifically intended for this purpose:

```js
var select = [2, 4];
var data = [{id: 1, name: "Param1"}, {id: 2, name: "Param2"},
            {id: 3, name: "Param3"}, {id: 4, name: "Param4"}]

var selectSet = new Set(select);
var result = data.filter( obj => selectSet.has(obj.id) );

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `for` loop as Liam's comment, or you can use the `filter` method of `array` like this:

```
var keys = [2, 4];
var objs = [{id: 1, name: "Param1"}, {id: 2, name: "Param2"}, {id: 3, name: "Param3"}, {id: 4, name: "Param4"}];

function filterById(obj) {
    return keys.indexOf(obj.id) != -1;
}
var newArr = objs.filter(filterById);
```

The `newArr` is the result you want.